# How to retrieve the value of 'Avengers'='Endgame'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

ET={'movies':[{'DC':'Batman','Marvel':[{'Avengers':'Endgame','Spiderman':'NowayHome'}]}]}

Comment: The Dictionary needs to be properly formatted before an answer can be given.

Comment: `Entertainment['other'][0]['movies']` if you put curly brackets on both ends like `{{'game':'football'}, {'other':[{'movies':'NowayHome'},{'songs':'latest'}]}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self explained

```
ET = {
    'movies': [{
        'DC': 'Batman',
        'Marvel': [{
            'Avengers': 'Endgame',
            'Spiderman': 'NowayHome'
        }]
    }]
}

'''
ET['movies'] => select key
ET['movies'][0] => select first list
ET['movies'][0]['Marvel'] => select key
.....
'''

Avengers = ET['movies'][0]['Marvel'][0]['Avengers']
print(Avengers) # Endgame
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Entertainment` is declared as

```
Entertainment = {'game':'football'}, {'other':[{'movies':'NowayHome'},{'songs':'latest'}]}
```

The answer will be

```py
Entertainment[1]['other'][0]['movies']
```